# Indentation in Power BI Matrix report

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to indent the rows in matrix report in Power BI, Like shown in this image:

[image: Like shown in this image]

The requirement is not to group, just the indentation for few metrics. Is it possible in Power BI?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no simple way of indenting a few out of many items in one dimension.

The only option I see is to calculate a weird table on the form:

[image]

And then write a fairly complex measure leveraging ISINSCOPE to determine what value to pull for e.g. sales for Banana (but not the sum of Mango, Papaya et al.)

Answer (score 0):

Use stepped layout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-matrix-visual#stepped-layout-with-matrix-visuals

It is one of the many settings for the matrix visual and well documented in the Microsoft docs.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I've used to indent rows in a matrix visual:

Create a table with the following code (column 2 just ensures the sort order):

```
Fruits_table = 
// Table columns
{
    ("Fruits",1),
    (REPT(UNICHAR(160),3)&"Apple",2),
    (REPT(UNICHAR(160),3)&"Banana",3),
    (REPT(UNICHAR(160),6)&"Mango",4),
    (REPT(UNICHAR(160),6)&"Papaya",5),
    (REPT(UNICHAR(160),6)&"Kiwi",6),
    (REPT(UNICHAR(160),6)&"Plum",7)
}
```

Then use the following measure to populate the column(s) in the visual:

```
Fruits column 1 = 
// Creates the 1st column of the fruits matrix visual
SWITCH(MAX('Fruits_table'[column_name]),
    "Fruits", [Fruits_measure],
    REPT(UNICHAR(160),3)&"Apple", [Apple_measure],
    REPT(UNICHAR(160),3)&"Banana", [Banana_measure],
    REPT(UNICHAR(160),6)&"Mango", [Mango_measure],
    REPT(UNICHAR(160),6)&"Papaya", [Papaya_measure],
    REPT(UNICHAR(160),6)&"Kiwi", [Kiwi_measure],
    REPT(UNICHAR(160),6)&"Plum", [Plum_measure]
    BLANK()
)
```

This should give you something like this:
[image]